# Characters with accents not interpreted correctly during update on sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, internationalization

I'm trying to update some records with Romanian text that have characters like 'ă, ț, î'

They are working fine if I copy the text manually using 'Edit rows' option on sql management studio but when I write an update statement **ă** gets interpreted as **a** and **ț** gets interpreted as **?**

However, **î** is interpreted correctly.

I've set the column data type as nvarchar(255) and the current collation is set to database default. I've tried Romanian as well but still no luck.

Below is an example query.

```
update dbo.tbl_romanian_test 
set title = 'ă ț î'
where Id = 1
```

Eventually I want this to be done from the app using Entity Framework. I would greatly appreciate any help. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to Add `N` before 'ă ț î' in your query as you are trying to Update a `NVARCHAR` column

```
update dbo.tbl_romanian_test 
set title = N'ă ț î'
where Id = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Turned out it was pretty simple. All I had to do was add 'N' infront of the text to explicitly state that it was nvarchar.

Working solution

```
update dbo.tbl_romanian_test 
set title = N'ă ț î'
where Id = 1
```